# What order preserving transformation makes data more evenly spread, decreasing the peak, and fattening the tails of the distribution?

Tags: data-transformation, kurtosis

How can I transform a variable (non linear transformation) such that its values are more evenly spread, that is reduce the peak in the middle of the histogram and move more into tails?

Comment: The methods described [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10975) give one approach out of the many possible.

Comment: Thanks... I'll use arctan(x) to stay within 0 an 1 (Probabilistic framework)... Skewed probabilities I should say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transform that most evens things out is the rank transform (just replace the data by the ranks).  If there are no ties then the result is uniform.

If data is fairly normal (bell shaped) then the inverse of the normal distribution will spread towards uniform.  Actually any s-shaped curve will tend to do this including the arctangent and inverse logit (center and choose an appropriate scale first).